# Multiplication using a kernel

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array

```
B = array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

I want to be able to sum the first 3 numbers using a kernel [1.0, -5.0, 1.0] and then take the mean. (1(1.0)-5(2)+1(2))/3.0 = -0.67 etc. The first and last element are kept but used to multiply.

The result will be this:

```
result = np.array([1.0, -0.67, -2.0, -3.33, 3.0]).
```

I would like an efficient way without loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get the middle elements using a convolution ([`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)) and dividing by the length of the kernel:

```
B = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
kernel = np.array([1.0, -5.0, 1.0])

tmp = np.convolve(B, kernel[::-1], mode='valid')/len(kernel)
```

*NB. a convolution uses the reverse of the kernel, so make sure you invert it if it is not symmetrical.*

Or use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

tmp = (swv(B, len(kernel))*kernel).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([-0.66666667, -2.        , -3.33333333])
```

Then concatenate the first and last elements, or replace the middle part in a copy of the array.

```
result = B.copy().astype(float)

start = len(kernel)//2
result[start:start+len(kernel)] = tmp
```

Output:

```
array([ 1.        , -0.66666667, -2.        , -3.33333333,  3.        ])
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I thought about this way but I felt it was alittle long.

Comment: If you want a vectorized approach, this seems the most appropriate way. For generic operations that wouldn't fit the convolution you could also use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html). See update.

Comment: Yeah i used sliding_window_view before but I wanted it with a kernel.